# ¿Cómo colocar en negrita el eje de un gráfico en ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
df<-data.frame(tt=c(3,6,2,7),pp=c("A","B","C","D"))
```

Y al graficar un gráfico de barras. Obtengo el resultado.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=pp, y=tt))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Mi consulta es. Cómo puedo hacer para que la letra C de mi gráfico sea negrita, solo la "C"

Lo deseado sería algo similar a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si puedes instalar el paquete [ggtext](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext): `install.packages("ggtext")` tienes la posibilidad de manejar estilos para muchos elementos gráficos, por ejemplo las etiquetas del eje x, incluso de forma individual:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

df %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(pp == 'C', 
                        paste0("<span style='color:blue;font-size:18pt'><b>", 
                               pp, '<b></span>'), pp),
         label = fct_reorder(label, pp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=label, y=tt))+
  geom_col()+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_markdown()
  )
```

Notas:

- `axis.text.x = element_markdown()` establece que el elemento es de tipo `markdown`, por lo que podrías simplemente definir los valores de `x` como `**<etiqueta>**`
- En el ejemplo, te puse también algunas configuraciones de estilo que son posibles aplicar individualmente a una determinada etiqueta
- Es importante reordenar `label` mediante `fct_reorder()` para que respete el mismo orden del dato crudo `pp`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.